# Entity Framework Override of Abstract Property Not Saved

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF5 Code First. I have a base class that includes an abstract property as such:

```
public abstract class BaseTransaction : EntityBase
{
    [Required]
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Policy Policy { get; set; }

    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public abstract double Premium { get; set; }
    public double Commission
    {
        get
        {
            return Premium * Policy.CommissionRate / 100;
        }
    }
}
```

I have several different descendant classes, each of which defines Premium differently. For some it simply stored with the class, for others it might be read only computed.

For example:

```
public class ManualQuote : BaseTransaction 
{
    public double Deductible { get; set; }
    public double ClaimLimit { get; set; }
    public double AggLimit { get; set; }
    public override double Premium { get; set; }
}
```

When I save a ManualQuote to the database, the first three properties are save to fields correctly. However, the data for Premium property is not save.  Am I doing something incorrectly or is this an issue with Entity Framework?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the abstract property even mapped to your database? Do you see the property as a field?

Comment: Good question. No, I don't see a field with that name in the db, even after I drop and recreate the database.

Comment: Well, than apparently EF does not like to pickup abstract fields.. consider making it virtual.

Comment: Have you tried code first migration? what was the scaffolded code for `Up` method. Didn't it included `Premium` property?

Comment: Why do you need to redefine Premium in ManualQuote when it already exists in BaseTransaction?  Eliminating Premium in ManualQuote will avoid the override which is causing the issue. you don't have to override the variable.  The override is causing the issue.

Comment: Changing from an abstract to a virtual in the base class resolved the issue. Thanks!